# Subscript to a subscript in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How do you make a subscript to a subscript in Illustrator? I don't see an option to do so under the Character option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such option In Illustrator.

One would need to either use a font which contains glyphs for subscripts of subscripts.

Or, *manually* adjust the type size and baseline shift for a given character.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the character(s) you wish to have as “double subscript,” you may use Unicode to produce it, as it contains characters which are precomposed as being subscripted. Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts for a list of available/possible characters.